# Barcode Scanner produces Chrome error

Tags: google-chrome, scanner

Using a 'Tera 2D Barcode Scanner' to scan QR codes into the url space of a browser. Each QR code is a unique URL used by employees to find parts in a system. The scanned QR codes are properly outputting (checked in a .txt file) the url. However when it is scanned into the browsers url space the page becomes, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Even if the code is scanned into a .txt and copy pasted into the url it returns the same error. What does this error mean in this context? Is the issue with the url or chrome?

Comment: Have you made sure, that there are no "invisible" characters (such as line breaks or NULs) after the URL?

Comment: There are not any in the .txt that I can find when I scan them into there

Comment: Are you sure, that the URL you scanned is valid? This sounds like an ASP.NET application forgetting to sanitze parameters or to trap a "not found" condition. Try the QR-Code of a known-good URL

Comment: It would seem you are correct, I generated a QR for another URL elsewhere on the same site and it worked fine. Additionally, if I type the URL in using only part of what teh scan puts in, the website loads as well.

Comment: Even if I create a separate QR for the address I am attempting to reach the error persists. Is it reasonable to assume the issue is with the URL that is trying to be reached?

Answer (score 0):

The issue, although not resolved, has been pin pointed. It is a separate issue from either of the two causes I originally surmised and lies with the developer of the software in use for the data base the QR codes are generated from. In three different cases, three different web pages are loaded. It is due to the specific information included, or in the case of the original question, excluded from the label overall and thus the QR code. So in some cases Eugen Rieck was correct that the browser was unable to handle an information "not found" condition.